# How do I put a variable in a geolocator.reverse() function?

Tags: python, geopy

I have `lat1` and `lng1` set. And when I try:

```
location = geolocator.reverse('lat1', 'lng1')
```

It gives me the error:

TypeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-bef81ce5884b> in <module>
----> 1 location = geolocator.reverse('lat1', 'lng1')

TypeError: reverse() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

and when I try it without the ',' it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Please post a proper [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(lat1, lng1))
```

The code above formats the variables as a string for the `.reverse()` method.

Comment: when I try that i get the error "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-80352a0482a1> in <module>
----> 1 print(location.address)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'
"

Comment: It should work. I used the following code: https://pastebin.com/Xdxruphv

Comment: It works thanks! Do you know if there is a way to get a part of a data table into geolocator.reverse()?

Comment: Do you mean something like a pandas dataframe? If so, you can use `df.iloc` to choose certain values based on the row and column and feed that into the reverse function using a loop.